# Perlin noise and negative coordinates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, perlin-noise

I am working with Perlin Noise and coordinates and want to know how to handle negative coordinates in order to make it not symmetric.

[Example image of my Perlin noise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI1PL.png)

As you can see in the image, when perlin noise get negatives coordinates it doesn't differ from positive so you get this symmetrical noise.

The code is obviously simple:

```
float extension = 0.005f;
float perlinNoise = Mathf.PerlinNoise((position.x + seed) * extension, (position.y + seed) * extension);
```

I want to know if there is an intelligent way to get normal noise.
BTW: Move away from 0,0 position or change it is not an option.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks like that's just how it is. You may have to offset it after all. I guess you could also write your own Perlin noise function.

Comment: you could always start at e.g. `-5000 + position.x + seed` or some other offset so you never reach a position where you cross `0`

Comment: Yes, I know that move away from 0,0 position would work but for example, how games like Minecraft handle it when you reach 0 coordinate?

Answer (score 0):

Answer by loominator199 · Oct 14, 2019 at 03:01 AM
Perlin noise is mirrored around zero coordinates. Use extra octaves to blend it in and hopefully hide it.

https://answers.unity.com/questions/991428/problem-with-perlin-noise-on-negative-coordinates.html